# How to view Horizontal scroll in the toolstripmenuitem

Tags: c#, winforms, horizontal-scrolling, toolstripmenu, toolstripitem

I have created a toolstipmenuitem in which i added a lot of toolstripmenuitems as sub menus.
And then i restricted the maximum size of the toolstripmenuitem which results in:

[image]

Vertical scrolling automatically becomes enabled as shown in the image.

But I need a horizontal scrolling. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: sorry. i have uploaded image..yes this is WinForms

Comment: @user2691432 - Did you try setting the `ToolStripMenuitem.DropDown.HScroll` property to true?

Comment: Menustrips do not support horizontal scrolling.  Vertical scrolling is provided but is pretty awkward to use.  This is not good UI, pop up a window with a ListView instead.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution:

1. Register for `MouseWheel`, `Opened`, `Closed` event of your `ToolStripDropDown` in the Load event of the form

```
    dropDown.Opened+= new EventHandler(dropDown_Opened);
    dropDown.Closed+= new ToolStripDropDownClosedEventHandler(dropDown_Closed);
    dropDown.MouseWheel+= new MouseEventHandler(dropDown_MouseWheel);
```

2. Add the code for Keyboard class which simulate key presses

```
    public static class Keyboard
    {            
         [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
         static extern uint keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
         const byte VK_UP = 0x26; // Arrow Up key
         const byte VK_DOWN = 0x28; // Arrow Down key
         const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001; //Key down flag, the key is going to be pressed
         const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002; //Key up flag, the key is going to be released
         public static void KeyDown()
         {
             keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
             keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
         }
         public static void KeyUp()
         {
            keybd_event(VK_UP, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
            keybd_event(VK_UP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
         }
    }
```

3. Add the code for `Opened`, `Closed`, `MouseWheel` events:

```
    bool IsMenuStripOpen  = false;
    void dropDown_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMenuStripOpen)
        {
            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                Keyboard.KeyUp();
            }
            else
            {
                Keyboard.KeyDown();
            }
        }
    }
    void dropDown_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsMenuStripOpen = false;
    }
    void dropDown_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsMenuStripOpen = true;
    }
```

4. Create global functionality for all systems for item 1

```
    void dropDownMenuScrollWheel(ToolStripDropDown dropDown)
    {
        dropDown.Opened +=new EventHandler(dropDown_Opened);
        dropDown.Closed +=new ToolStripDropDownClosedEventHandler(dropDown_Closed);
        dropDown.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(dropDown_MouseWheel);
   }
```

ToolStripDropDown is `ToolStripMenuItem.DropDown`

Hope it help you.